# Make next div stay below the current one

Tags: html, css

Following this question: [Responsive table with vertical and horizontal headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410762/responsive-table-with-vertical-and-horizontal-headers/29411406)

I've encountered this problem ([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwYedv)):

[image]

I want the second table to go below the first one. I can achieve that by spamming a few `<br>`. But there must be a better way of doing this...

Here's my **CSS**:

```
    .aa table {
  border-collapse: collapse;  
} 

.aa td, .aa th {
  border: 1px #ddd solid;
}
.aa table {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.aa td, .aa th {
  padding: 10px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 640px) {


   .aa table  {
      float: left;
     display: block;
   }


   .aa table ~ table td, 
   .aa table ~ table th  { border-left: 0;  }

   .aa table ~ table tr:first-child  th:first-child  { display: none; }
   .aa table ~ table tr:not(:first-child) th  { display: none; }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Table 1 -->
<h3>Table 1</h3>
<div class='aa'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">BMW</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">GPS</th>
        <td>12001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Bluetooth</th>
        <td>7001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sensors</th>
        <td>12301</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Audi</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">GPS</th>
        <td>10001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Bluetooth</th>
        <td>8201</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sensors</th>
        <td>10501</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Mercedes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">GPS</th>
        <td>14201</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Bluetooth</th>
        <td>6201</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sensors</th>
        <td>11701</td>
    </tr>
</table>
  <!--<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>-->
</div>
<h3>Table 2</h3>
<!-- Table 2-->
<div class='aa'>
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">BMW</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">GPS</th>
        <td>1200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Bluetooth</th>
        <td>700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sensors</th>
        <td>1230</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Audi</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">GPS</th>
        <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Bluetooth</th>
        <td>820</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sensors</th>
        <td>1050</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Mercedes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">GPS</th>
        <td>1420</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Bluetooth</th>
        <td>620</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sensors</th>
        <td>1170</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using separate tables for showing that audi, gps etc?

Comment: @Lal : It's more of hack to get it to display nicely in both desktop and mobile devices. The original idea comes from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29410762/responsive-table-with-vertical-and-horizontal-headers/29411406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/tLyfmbxd/)

This behaviour is due to the `float:left` that you have used for `.aa table`. so for cancelling the float that you have used, youll have to clear the float applied. So you can use `clear: both;` for that. So kindly add a style for `h3` as follows

```
h3{
      clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The aa table class is your problem.  If you float left, all tables will be side-by-side.  So to solve the problem, you either have to remove that declaration, or clear the float.

It could be as simple as:

```
<table>
      ...
</table>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<table>
      ...
</table>


.clearfix {
   clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can make this work by modifying your table container `div` elements to use the style `display: inline-block`.

So you can simply add a style to your `aa` class like:

```
.aa {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can check out the [updated codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPGEWR).

Comment: inline-block will float them side-by-side.  He wants one below the other.

Comment: @bpeterson76 it seems to work correctly with this codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPGEWR

Comment: True, but it also removes the float....which was my point.  The float was the problem.